# angular ngShow with animate.css

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, animate.css

I want to animate the showing and hiding of an element using [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) and angular.

I have read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994706/using-ng-animate-with-animate-css) and the angular documentation for `ngShow` and `ngAnimate` but still cannot get it to work.

I have tried the following setup on plunker, but it doesn't work.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.show = true;
});
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Show: {{show}}</p>
    <div class="show" ng-click="show = !show" ng-show="show === true">Show is true</div>
    <div class="hide" ng-click="show = !show" ng-show="show === false">Show is false</div>
</body>
```

**style.css**

```
.show.ng-hide-add {
   animation: fadeOut 5s linear;
}
```

When clicking on "show is true" (and therefor hiding it) I see it wait for 5 second before hiding, so there is *something* happening, but it doesn't fade out.

I can make it work if I add this to the css:

```
.show.ng-hide-add {
    opacity: 1.0;
    display: block !important;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.show.ng-hide-add-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**However, I don't want to do it this way**. I want to use [animate.css's keyframes](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) (I think that's the correct term, my css lingo isn't brilliant) such as `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` etc..

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KHILPlfRzLfNAbkuEl1e?p=preview) to show what I am seeing.

What am I doing wrong? How can I use animate.css's keyframe animations with angular's `ngAnimate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `.ng-hide` class, as it's the class that is assigned once the condition in `ng-show` is false, or in `ng-hide` is true.

According to that you can edit your code like this:

```css
.show.ng-hide,
.hide.ng-hide{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

.show,
.hide{
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<p>Show: {{show}}</p>

<div class="show" ng-click="show = !show" ng-show="show">Show</div>
<div class="hide" ng-click="show = !show" ng-hide="show">Hide</div>
```

-

**EDIT:**

In case you want to use the animate.css classes, for example `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut` you have to assign the corresponding keyframes inside your css.

So you have to use the following CSS:

```
.show.ng-hide,
.hide.ng-hide{
  animation-name:fadeOut;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}

.show{
  animation-name:fadeIn;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** 
In order to make it work correctly in the plunker I have not used the 3.2.0 version suggested by the plunker external library finder, but I manually linked the 3.5.1 version adding the following code in the html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.css" />
```

-

**[Working Plunker with full code](https://plnkr.co/edit/SNBwAl7VEIDowIFiKwy1)**

Comment: I am able to get it work if I add my own css transitions using the second piece of code I posted. *However*, I stated in my question that I wanted to use animate.css keyframe animations. `fadeIn`, `zoomOut` etc. I will edit my question to try make it a little less confusing. Sorry.

Comment: @MattLishman: see the edit in my answer and let me know if it works out for you. I updated the Plunker example too.

Comment: Ah! In your plunker you use a different version of animate.css than me. Using that same version (using plunkers library feature, which I didn't use for animate.css, for some reason...) my original code works. So you answered my question, but in a different way.  Although your answer is still useful for others, if you want to add that to your answer I can accept it.

Comment: @MattLishman sure I'm adding it right now. I had the same problem with plunker library feature and end up copy and pasting the link from cdnjs.com

Comment: Thanks for the help, even if it was indirect!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this

```
<div ng-show="show">
    <div class="show" ng-click="show = !show">Show</div>
</div>
<div ng-show="!show">
    <div class="hide" ng-click="show = !show" >Hide</div>
</div>

.show.ng-hide{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
.show{
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  opacity:1;
}
```